# How to solve Unhandled rejection TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON for jwt.sign

Tags: javascript, json, request, jwt

When I try to create a token for a user like in **this code** :

```
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');
const passport = require('passport');
const Patient = require('../models').Patient;

module.exports = {
    retrieve(req, res) {
        return Patient
            .find({
                where: {
                    email: req.body.email,
                }
            })
            .then(patient => {
                if (!patient) return res.json({
                    success: false,
                    msg: 'Patient not found'
                });
                const result = Patient.build().verifyPassword(req.body.password, patient.password);
                if (!result) {
                    return res.json({
                        success: false,
                        msg: 'wrong password'
                    });
                } else {
                    const token = jwt.sign(patient, secret, {
                        expiresIn: 604800 // 1 week
                    });
                    return res.status(201).send(patient);
                }
            })

    },
    //
};
```

I get this error :

> Unhandled rejection TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON
>       at Object.stringify (native)
>       at toString (/home/omarou/Documents/Projet/PharmaLiv/node_modules/jws/lib/tostring.js:9:15)
>       at jwsSecuredInput (/home/omarou/Documents/Projet/PharmaLiv/node_modules/jws/lib/sign-stream.js:12:34)
>       at Object.jwsSign [as sign] (/home/omarou/Documents/Projet/PharmaLiv/node_modules/jws/lib/sign-stream.js:22:22)
>       at Object.module.exports [as sign] (/home/omarou/Documents/Projet/PharmaLiv/node_modules/jsonwebtoken/sign.js:146:16)
>       at Model.Patient.find.then.patient (/home/omarou/Documents/Projet/PharmaLiv/server/controllers/patients.js:27:39)
>       at Model.tryCatcher (/home/omarou/Documents/Projet/PharmaLiv/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/util.js:16:23)
>       at Promise._settlePromiseFromHandler (/home/omarou/Documents/Projet/PharmaLiv/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:512:31)
>       at Promise._settlePromise (/home/omarou/Documents/Projet/PharmaLiv/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:569:18)
>       at Promise._settlePromise0 (/home/omarou/Documents/Projet/PharmaLiv/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:614:10)
>       at Promise._settlePromises (/home/omarou/Documents/Projet/PharmaLiv/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:693:18)
>       at Async._drainQueue (/home/omarou/Documents/Projet/PharmaLiv/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/async.js:133:16)
>       at Async._drainQueues (/home/omarou/Documents/Projet/PharmaLiv/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/async.js:143:10)
>       at Immediate.Async.drainQueues (/home/omarou/Documents/Projet/PharmaLiv/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/async.js:17:14)
>       at runCallback (timers.js:651:20)
>       at tryOnImmediate (timers.js:624:5)

`controllers/patients.js:27:39` refer to the method jwt.sign on my code

It tells that it's coming from the jwt.sign method

Anyone can tell me what's the matter ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

"circular structure" means that something in the object you are trying to return contains a reference to itself or to a thing that it is contained in. This sort of structure can't easily be serialized.

It looks like the problem must be in the structure of your Patient object itself. You will need to simplify it for signing or sending over the wire

Comment: My structure is like this 
`id: {
        allowNull: false,
        autoIncrement: true,
        primaryKey: true,
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER
      },
      email: { 
        type: Sequelize.STRING, 
        allowNull: false
      },
      password : { 
        type: Sequelize.STRING, 
        allowNull: false
      },
      createdAt: {
        allowNull: false,
        type: Sequelize.DATE
      },
      updatedAt: {
        allowNull: false,
        type: Sequelize.DATE
      }
    });`

what do you recommend me to change ? thanks :)

Comment: for example when I make a request for a patient my object contain this :

`  "patient": {
    "id": 7,
    "email": "dupont@gmail.com",
    "password": "$2a$08$wqgTg8.DSPT.BJHM.BQV/eq5oQBXwGnxH49GlP1A2YMlGRsmYKNy.",
    "createdAt": "2017-03-21T15:34:40.977Z",
    "updatedAt": "2017-03-21T15:34:40.977Z"
  } `


I don't see any circular structure on it

Comment: That does look fine. Are you sure the error is being generated in the jwt.sign() ?

Comment: please check the error I edited on the initial post,
I think it's jwt.sign because of `controllers/patients.js:27:39` refer to this method

Comment: If you look into `node_modules/jws/lib/sign-stream.js:12:34` you might be able to see what it is calling `toString` on when it hits the error

Answer (score 1):

I found the mistake 
the object patient has too much methods that make the circular structure.
so I created a variable playload that contains the variable that I need for authentication.

```
const payload = {email: patient.username, password: patient.password};
                    const token = jwt.sign(payload, secret, {
                        expiresIn: 604800 // 1 week
                    });
```

it works now thanks to  @andrewMcGuinness for his answer :)